# SharePoint 2013 Designer Workflow Overdue mail not getting triggered

Tags: 2013, workflow

I created a SharePoint 2013 Designer Workflow. And in assign task I configured Overdue emails daily.

But when assign task triggers it sends TASK CREATION email but overdue mail is not getting triggered.

[image]

Please help resolving this issue.

Answer (score 2):

This may be the silly answer, but I noticed that the Due Date field isn't set in your screenshot - in my experience it has to be set there (it can't be added later) to trigger the overdue emails. Usually what I do is use the action "Add time to date" to add two weeks or whatever to [Today] and then use the resulting variable to populate that Due Date field.